# asp.net vb.net can any one explain what is wrong?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

What is wrong with this code?

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    Do
        Response.Write("hello")
    Loop While i < 5
End Sub
```

I have Error

```
System.OutOfMemoryException was unhandled
Insufficient memory to continue the execution of the program.
```

Can anyone explain why I have that error?

Comment: You never increment i.  So your loop goes on forever

Comment: @DavidCram That was my first thought too, but I'm having trouble figuring out why that's causing an `OutOfMemoryException`. I'm wondering if it's buffering the Response.Write output and he's eventually blowing whatever memory is available for that buffer.

Comment: @DavidCram thanx it's Solve my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the fixed version of your code:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    Do
        Response.Write("hello")
        i = i + 1
    Loop While i < 5
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

So your question is "why out of memory". Because the .NET Framework can only access so much memory. Essentially your loop says "keep burning up memory until the computer crashes or Jesus comes back". Since Armageddon has not occurred and the Framework has protection against crashing the computer, your intended outcome fails and it, instead, throws an out of memory error when you burn through memory with your loop that has no termination clause or an increment to avoid looping forever (or until the Framework stops you from crashing the computer). ;-)